# Как сделать постоянное обновление данных в окне

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, tkinter

У меня есть метод, который проходит по моему списку с пользователями и выводит их данные в окно.

```
def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x400+300+200')

    for x in all_users:
        label = Label(text=x)
        label.pack()

    mainloop()
```

В другом потоке выполняется метод, в котором пользователь оставляет свои данные и добавляется в список all_users. 
Изначально all_users пуст. При запуске этих методов в разных потоках у меня создается пустое окно, во время выполнения программы список all_users наполняется данными, но к методу window() программа больше не возвращается и 
данные в окне не обновляются. 
У меня была идея поместить часть кода в цикл, чтобы список постоянно проверялся на наличие пользователей и в дальнейшем окно обновлялось, но логично, что создавалось множество окон с одним пользователем.

```
while True:
    for x in all_users:
        label = Label(text=x)
        label.pack()
        mainloop()
```

Можно ли как-нибудь возвращаться к методу window() через определенный промежуток времени, чтобы окно обновляло данные? Или как лучше реализовать данную задачу?

Данный код обновляет данные в окне, но только тогда, когда закроешь текущее окно. А вот как реализовать без закрытия окна?

```
def window():
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+300+200')
for x in all_users:
    label = Label()
    label.config(text=x)
    label.pack()
mainloop()
while True:
    window()
```

Comment: а не проще создать 1 `Label` и прост ого обновлять при помощь `label.config(text=x)`

Comment: label.config(text=x) написать в Window()? тогда при запуске программы откроется пустое окно без каких-либо данных, а когда будет наполняться список all_users, то окно будет просто открыто и никакие данные в него не добавятся т.к. к методу window() программа больше не вернется и строчка label.config(text=x) не выполниться

Comment: Где-то тут был почти такой же вопрос с моим ответом (вопрос куда-то пропал и ответ тоже), там был пример, как сделать то что вам нужно через root.after

Comment: Кажется понимаю о чем вы, но если root.after расположить после строки mainloop(), то постоянно будет создаваться новое окно, а если перед, то окно создаваться не будет, так? Получается, что надо сделать проверку на существование окна и, если окно существует, то вызывать root.after()? По-сути это то же самое, что и вызывать метод window() в цикле while, только в after с задержкой. Я не знаю, как проверить окно на существование

Comment: @Дима, после mainloop не должно быть ничего: это "вечный" цикл, он крутится пока существует окно. Все инициализации должны выполняться до mainloop. В моем примере было показано как это сделать. Вообще, удалять вопрос, когда на него уже есть ответ - дурной тон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы пишете консольную программу, код у вас выполняется последовательно: например, сначала запрашиваются входные данные, потом выполняются вычисления, потом выдается результат.

При создании оконных приложений (в том числе с помощью tkinter) обычно используется [**событийно-ориентированное программирование**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Суть вкратце такова: в программу извне (например, от операционной системы) поступают события - клики мышью, нажатия клавиш клавиатуры, срабатывания таймера, перемещения окна, событие "необходимости перерисовки" окна и т.д. Код (кроме инициализаций) выполняется не последовательно сам по себе, а в ответ на возникновение этих событий. В программе есть цикл обработки событий, который достает событие из очереди, смотрит, привязана ли к нему функция-обработчик, вызывает ее (если она есть). Функции-обработчики событий привязываются к событиям **до** запуска цикла обработки.

В tkinter цикл обработки сообщений скрыт внутри метода `mainloop` главного окна. Цикл условно бесконечный - он работает пока существует окно. Поэтому весь код, работающий с данным окном должен либо выполниться до запуска цикла обработки сообщений, либо находиться в функциях-обработчиках, но не ниже вызова `mainloop`.

**Других бесконечных циклов в программе нужно избегать** *(если такой цикл не выполняется в отдельном потоке)*, иначе получится, что выход из функции-обработчика в основной цикл обработки сообщений не произойдет, и окно зависнет.

Для выполнения периодических действий существуют специальные объекты-таймеры, которые умеют посылать окну события с определенной периодичностью. В tkinter создание таймера (одноразового) реализуется с помощью метода `after`. Пример:

```
from tkinter import *

all_users = ['Alex', 'Sam', 'Bob']
i = 0

root = Tk()

label = Label()  # создаем метку без текста
label.pack()

def next_user():
    label.configure(text=all_users[i]) # берем имя пользователя, выводим в label
    i += 1
    if i < len(all_users):  # если пользователи еще остались
        root.after(1000, next_user)  # через одну секунду еще раз выполнить next_user

root.after(1000, next_user)  # ставим таймер, чтобы через секунду выполнилась функция next_user
# или просто вызываем next_user(), чтобы первый пользователь был показан сразу, а следующие с паузой

mainloop()
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы создание окна было в отдельном методе для того, чтобы запустить метод в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Логичнее наоборот - создание окна делать в основном потоке, а если что-то длительное должно выполняться параллельно - то это делать в отдельном потоке.