# Помогите найти ошибку. Модуль Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть рабочий код, его функция состоит в том, что пользователь с помощью клавиш управляет шариком:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

circle = canvas.create_oval((150, 100, 170, 120), fill='yellow')
vx = 0
vy = 0


def on_key_press(event):
    global vx, vy
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        vx = -10
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        vx = 10
    elif event.keysym == 'Up':
        vy = -10
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        vy = 10


def on_key_release(event):
    global vx, vy
    if event.keysym in ('Left', 'Right'):
        vx = 0
    elif event.keysym in ('Up', 'Down'):
        vy = 0


root.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_key_release)


def game_loop():
    canvas.move(circle, vx, vy)
    root.after(50, game_loop)#Эту строку я изменяю


game_loop()

root.mainloop()
```

Но когда я изменяю root.after(50,  game_loop) (Указано в коде) на две строчки, которые по логике должны работать:

```
time.sleep(0.5)
game_loop()
```

То программа запускает окно, рисует шарик и стопорится(Управлять нельзя), но не выдаёт ошибку. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Управлять шариком нельзя потому что вы не понимаете как работает функция sleep

Comment: И использование глобальных переменных плохая практика

Comment: Ну как я понял root.after(x,f) через x времени выполняет функцию f, почему нельзя с помощью sleep притормозить программу на x времени, а затем выполнить функцию f?

Comment: Ну after же позволяет задать любую задержку? плюс это родное для Tk, я не пойму что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Я хочу разобраться почему не работает альтернативный вариант со sleep, ведь по сути там происходит одно и тоже

Comment: @ВладАпухтин, посмотрите объяснение в этом ответе: [Как сделать постоянное обновление данных в окне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939189/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя `sleep()`, вы ломаете цикл. `after()`, в отличии от `sleep()`, запускается в фоновом процессе.

Comment: after не запускается в отдельном процессе (запустив внутри обработчика бесконечный цикл все так же можно "сломать" работу mainloop). Скорее всего в очередь событий просто добавляется событие с определенным временем срабатывания, которое крутится в этой очереди, пока время срабатывания не наступит.