# Зависает кнопка в tkinter при использовании while True

Tags: python, tkinter, while

В интерфейсе вводится время, подтверждается нажатием кнопки Ok и по его достижении выполняется URL-запрос. Программа работает, запрос выполняется, но до этого момента приложение висит. В чём моя ошибка?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import datetime
import urllib.request
from time import sleep

def timer():
    start_time=entry_1.get()
    while True:
        if str(start_time) == datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H.%M"):
            urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:8088/API/?Function=StartRecording')
            break
        sleep(1)

root=tk.Tk()

label_1= ttk.Label(root, text="Начать запись в (формат 00.00) ")
label_1.pack(side="left")

entry_1= ttk.Entry(root)
entry_1.pack(side="left")

greet_button= ttk.Button(root, text="Ok", command=timer)
greet_button.pack(side="left")

quit_button=ttk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
quit_button.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Sleep в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-в-tkinter)

Comment: Также к прочтению, о событийно-ориентированном программировании и tkinter: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939189/1365

Answer (score 2):

Помог `import threading` и замена `command=timer` на:

```
command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=timer, daemon=True).start()
```